# Why FOCUSED_STATE_SET is array

Tags: android, android-view

Docs says:
Indicates the view is focused.

Why FOCUSED_STATE_SET is array.

```
protected static final int[] FOCUSED_STATE_SET
```

So it should be one value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first clue is that the documentation tells us to that [`FOCUSED_STATE_SET`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#FOCUSED_SELECTED_STATE_SET) is a state that is used for Drawables, particularly [`getDrawableState()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#getDrawableState()).

Another clue as to what it does is the fact that this is static and final, meaning it is a constant, not that it describes the current state of any particular View.

`FOCUSED_STATE_SET` describes a state indicating that a View is focused. "Set" in this context doesn't mean a true or false "is this thing set," but describes the focused state *as a set of multiple states*.

We can [look at the definition](https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_base/blob/master/core/java/android/view/View.java#L1559) of the many `_STATE_SET` constants in the View class and see what they actually contain. Indeed, many of these constants contain multiple states, such as `SELECTED_WINDOW_FOCUSED_STATE_SET`, which describes the combination of `StateSet.VIEW_STATE_WINDOW_FOCUSED` and `StateSet.VIEW_STATE_SELECTED`.

`FOCUSED_STATE_SET` is just `StateSet.VIEW_STATE_FOCUSED`, but is still an array so it is a valid state for `Drawable#getDrawableState()`.